# How to setup WSO2 Identitiy Server to skip authentication challenge page on OAuth2?

Tags: wso2, msf4j, wso2-identity-server

We are currently looking into WSO2 products for a new project. We want Identity Server to manage users (either direct sign-ups or via common OAuth2 providers, like Facebook) and authenticate users on some Microservice using [MSF4J](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j).

Following these example I managed to setup a test environment, where a user can register via WSO2 IDS REST API and then authenticate at the MicroServicea any time while being logged in.

Now since we both run the Identity Server and the Microservice as our own backend for mobile app, we wan't to get rid of the authentication challenge step each new user has to take.

**Is there a way to automatically set the permission for each user to access the Microservice without this web prompt?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip OAuth2/OpenIdConnect user consent page by enabling below configuration under `<OpenIDConnect>` in `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`

```
<SkipUserConsent>true</SkipUserConsent>
```